# Append <li class> to <ul class> with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

When I run the function in the browser, "[object Object]" shows up instead of the text stored inside the variable $new_comment. I wish to append user inputs.

**HTML :**

```
<li class="list-group-item">"User comments"</li>

<div class="comments">
    <ul class="list-group"></ul>
</div>
```

**Js :**

```
var addCommentFromInputBox = function() {
    var $new_comment;

    if ($(".input-group input").val() !== "") {
        $new_comment = $("<p>").text($(".input-group input").val());
        $new_comment.hide();

        $(".list-group").append('<li class="list-group-item">' + ($new_comment) + '</li>');
        $new_comment.fadeIn();
        $(".input-group input").val("");
    }
};
```

Everything runs fine when I change the code to:

```
$(".list-group").append($new_comment);
```

But I wish to style it with Bootstrap.

Comment: Have you tried to do the following: `$(".list-group").html($(".list-group").html() + '<li class="list-group-item">' + ($new_comment) + '</li>');`

Answer (score 1):

You can use it something like this `$(".list-group").append($('<li class="list-group-item"></li>').html($new_comment));`

**Here this the full demo code**

```js
addCommentFromInputBox = function() {
        var $new_comment;

        if ($(".input-group input").val() !== "") {
            $new_comment = $("<p>").text($(".input-group input").val());
            $new_comment.hide();

            $(".list-group").append($('<li class="list-group-item"></li>').html($new_comment));
            $new_comment.fadeIn();
            $(".input-group input").val("");
        }
  }

addCommentFromInputBox();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="comments">
            <ul class="list-group">
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks Bhavin for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
var listGroupItem = $('<li class="list-group-item"></li>').html($new_comment)
$(".list-group").append($listGroupItem);
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what your code does, and why it should work.